# Find the derivative of $y=7^{x^2}+10$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of $y=7^{x^2}+10$.

I tried the logarithmic differentiation as follows

$y=7^{x^2}+10$

$\ln y=\ln (7^{x^2}+10)$

But I can't simplify the left hand side more to be able to differentiate it.

Then I tried using the exponential function

$y=7^{x^2}+10$

$ e^y=e^{7^{x^2}+10}$

$e^y=e^{7^{x^2}} \times e^{10}$

Then differentiating both sides gives

$e^y \frac{dy}{dx} = e^{7^{x^2}} \times \frac{d}{dx} (7^{x^2}) \times e^{10} $

Now put $t=7^{x^2}$, then

$\ln t=\ln (7^{x^2})=x^2 \times \ln 7$

differentiating both sides

$\frac{1}{t} \frac{dt}{dx} = 2x \times \ln 7$

Then $\frac{dt}{dx}=  \frac{d}{dx} (7^{x^2})= 2\ln (7) \ x \times 7^{x^2}$.

As a result, $e^y \frac{dy}{dx}=e^{7^{x^2}} \times 2\ln (7) \ x \times 7^{x^2} \times e^{10}=e^{7^{x^2}+10} \times 2\ln (7) \ x \times 7^{x^2}=e^{y} \times 2\ln (7) \ x \times 7^{x^2}$. And then $\frac{dy}{dx}=2\ln (7) \ x \times 7^{x^2}$

But I feel like there is way shorter solution. If there is any solution, especially using logarithmic differentiation, I would like if you could share it. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $b^u = e^{u \ln b}.$ This is the most direct.

Comment: With logarithmic differentiation: $y-10=7^{x^2}$, so $\ln(y-10)=\ln(7) x^2 $. Differentiating both sides we get $\dfrac{1}{y-10} \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2\ln(7)x$, and then…

Comment: @SeanRoberson Got it! Thank you.

Comment: @azif00 Thank you so much, I see now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat shorter than what you did:

$\qquad~~~\begin{align}y&=7^{x^2}+10
\\
y-10&=7^{x^2}
\\
\ln(y-10) &= x^2 \ln(7)\end{align}$

using implicit differentiation gives

$\qquad\begin{align}\frac{1}{(y-10)}\frac{dy}{dx}&=2x\ln(7)
\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=2x\ln(7)\cdot(y-10)
\\
&=2x\ln(7)\,7^{x^2}\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

If $u = 7^{x^2}$, then $\log u = x^2 \log 7$, so $\frac{u'}{u} = 2x \log 7$ and we have $u' = (2x\log 7)\cdot 7^{x^2}$

Now we have $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}7^{x^2}+\frac{d}{dx}10=\frac{d}{dx}7^{x^2} = (2x\log 7)\cdot 7^{x^2}$$